# Why isn't search working in Finder?

Tags: macos, search

In Finder, the search bar in the top right corner has ceased to function. Observe:

[image: failed search]

Obviously, there *should* be something with the letter "s" in it. But no results appear. It's just blank. Anything I search for, anywhere I search for it, it all fails.

Comment: Just curious, is a little wheel (or gear) spinning in the right-hand corner?

Comment: @daviesgeek Nope.

Comment: Can you please open your activity monitor and check if mdworker service is running?

Comment: @doc_180 Not on my Mac right now, but when I get home I'll do that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<strike>Other than your Finder having jaundice</strike>, this should be a simple fix. The following command will clear the volumes local store and rebuild it if necessary; Open up Terminal and type:

```
# sudo mdutil -E /
```

- You will be asked for your password, provide it, as this command
  requires administrator privileges to run.
- After confirming your Spotlight index will be re-built and your files
  should appear in the search. ( Depending on the size of your HDD it
  can take a while )

---

To check if all volumes have indexing enabled or disabled use:

```
# mdutil -s -a
```

To toggle (enable/disable) indexing on all volumes:

```
# mdutil -a -i
```

These commands are safe to use when/if you encounter similar issues as described in the question.

---

Complete options available:

```
 -p  Spotlight caches indexes of some network devices locally.  This option requests
     that a local caches be flushed to the appropriate network device.

 -E  This flag will cause each local store for the volumes indicated to be erased.
     The stores will be rebuilt if appropriate.

 -i on | off
     Sets the indexing status for the provided volumes to on or off.  Note that index-
     ing may be delayed due to low disk space or other conditions.

 -s  Display the indexing status of the listed volumes.

 -a  Apply command to all volumes.

 -v  Print verbose information when available.
```

- [mdutil(1) Mac OS X Manual Page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mdutil.1.html)

Comment: heh, looks like it got over it ;-)

Comment: Yep, I realized it was disturbingly yellow, and switched it to a more soothing grey.

Comment: No problem at all -- quick and easy. Make sure you check the answer as correct. take care.

Comment: I will, once it lets me. Another 2 minutes.

Comment: This worked at first, now I'm back to the same old problem, but this just says "Indexing and Searching Disabled" when I put it in Terminal.

Comment: @Mahnax is indexing enabled? To turn it on (or to make sure it's on) for all volumes, use `sudo mdutil -a -i on` in Terminal and then use the command @ioi provided.

Comment: @Mahnax, you can check the status of spotlight indexing by using: `mdutil -s -a`. This will display if any volume is `enabled` or `disabled` for indexing. The command @koiyu has provided is a toggle switch to enable or disable indexing. I'm disappointed you unaccepted my answer, oh well. Happy indexing!

Comment: Sorry, but it just stopped working. If that works, I'd suggest adding it to your answer, and I'll re-accept for good.

Comment: No worries at all. I'll keep my fingers crossed for you too, since there aren't too many more `mdutil` commands left in the playbook.

Comment: So it would seem.

Answer (score 1):

Being as the UI is a better way to go than to jump right away into Terminal, try the following from [Apple's support documentation](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2409):

1. From the Apple menu, choose System Preferences.
2. Click Spotlight.
3. Click the Privacy tab.
4. Drag a folder or even an entire volume (your hard drive) to the list.
5. Remove the item or volume you just added.

Failing these steps and the steps advised by the others, try creating a new user and seeing if search works in Finder. If it still does not work, then search is broken system-wide and an Archive & Install will not help. You'll want to back up your data and reinstall the OS. If an Apple Store is close, they can be of assistance here (no charge).